# What Objective-C type should I use in CoreData for large amounts of content?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am working on an app for reading articles (short to medium form, think 300 to 3,000 words). I will sync with a server and store the content locally in a CoreData model. What is the best type to use for the content field? What is the most efficient from a performance perspective?

Comment: You could save your text as file in the documents directory and save the location in your model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's just plain text, store it in a Core Data string attribute, which corresponds to instances of `NSString`. Converting it to other formats isn't going to get you anything. If it's rich text of some kind, you'll probably want to use a Core Data binary attribute (== instances of `NSData` when reading/writing).